# XML Sitemap stopped working

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

I don`t know exactly when but it seems to me after upgrade of some modules and core, sitemap stopped working. Using latest Drupal 7.17 and XML Sitemap 7.x-2.0-rc1

You can see it with some kind of error here http://www.testtest.detect.by/sitemap.xml (Use Firefox to get it displayed)

How could i know what`s the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check this post http://www.bytechip.com/2010/05/xml-parsing-error/ , it tells changes in .htaccess file may cause this

Comment: I am having Cache Booster (which has some settings in .htaccess) enabled but the sitemap later worked properly with and .htaccess did not changed.

Answer (score 1):

Your sitemap seems to work. When viewing the source of your sitemap, the XML needed for crawlers is displayed.

If you're talking about the blank page you get to see when viewing it in your browser: see if you've enabled the "include stylesheet for humans" option in the configuration of the module.

Comment: It worked for a year (stylesheet is enabled). Then suddenly an error (you can see it in firefox)

Comment: You can [validate](http://www.validome.org/google/validate?url=http://www.testtest.detect.by/sitemap.xml&lang=en&googleTyp=SITEMAP) your Sitemap to check for any errors. Looks like stylesheet is misssing but XML generated is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The error Firefox shows is for the sitemap.xsl file.

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
>   Location: http://www.testtest.detect.by/sitemap.xsl
>   Line Number 1, Column 2:
>    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
>   -^

I tried validating the file with the [Nu Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/nu/?parser=xml&doc=http://www.testtest.detect.by/sitemap.xsl), and it shown the following error:

> Fatal Error: required character (found ) (expected `<`)
>   At line 1, column 2
>
> `<?xml version=`

The problem is caused by a space before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.

The first lines of sitemap.xsl are the following ones.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- Copyright (c) 2010  Dave Reid <http://drupal.org/user/53892>

     This file is free software: you may copy, redistribute and/or modify it
     under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the
     Free Software Foundation, either version 2 of the License, or (at your
     option) any later version.

     This file is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
     WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
     MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
     General Public License for more details.

     You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
     along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

     This file incorporates work covered by the following copyright and
     permission notice:

     Google Sitmaps Stylesheets (GSStylesheets)
     Project Home: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gstoolbox
     Copyright (c) 2005 Baccou Bonneville SARL (http://www.baccoubonneville.com)
     License http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/lesser.html GNU/LGPL -->
```

That space is not present in the [file that is used to create the output](http://drupalcode.org/project/xmlsitemap.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/xsl/xmlsitemap.xsl) for http://www.testtest.detect.by/sitemap.xsl, though.